# prevent space from stop scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, keydown

So i have made this lille website where you can get a stick man to walk by scrolling down, mouse or down arrow key.

I just made a little function to make the spacebar a jump button, the only problem is that if i use the down arrow key to scroll the jump stop the scrolling.

should i add something to the space button, this is what i got so far:

```
$(document).keydown(function (evt) {
console.log("Key pressed: " + evt.keyCode);

if(evt.keyCode == 32) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#mand").css("bottom", "300px");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#mand").css("bottom", "140px");
    },500);},0); 
}
});
```

it does not work in fiddle or code pen don't know why but:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GcwlA

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: it does not work in fiddle or code pen don't know why but: 

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GcwlA